Optimizing C library with global variables for cross-platform dynamic linking in Lazarus IDE
I'm developing a C library for parsing configuration (.ini) files, which I plan to dynamically link with a UI created in Lazarus IDE. Currently, my C code heavily relies on global variables, as shown in this simplified example:
// Global variables in C
char nom_fichier_param[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
char nom_fichier_parametre[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
double temps_mesure, teta, pre_retard;
int filtre_tot, filtre_coinc;

void lecture_parametres(void) {
    char s[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    FILE *f;
    int v_t;
    int erreur;

    CodeSortie = 0;


    // Construct the full file path
    snprintf(nom_fichier_param, sizeof(nom_fichier_param), "%s%s%s", chemin_param, nom_fichier_parametre, EXTENSION_PARAM);
    f = fopen(nom_fichier_param, "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        CodeSortie = 1;
        return;
    }


    // Determine mode based on filename
    mode = (strstr(nom_fichier_param, "A.ini") != NULL) ? 'A' : 'P';
    // Skip the remaining 5 header lines
    for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {
        if (fgets(s, sizeof(s), f) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected end of file\n");
            fclose(f);
            CodeSortie = 1;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Process "temps_mesure"
    //fgets(s, sizeof(s), f);
    erreur = sscanf(DSp(trimRight(strncpy(s, s + 39, 40))), "%lf", &temps_mesure);
    if (erreur == 0) {
        printf("ERREUR format \"temps de mesure\"\n");
        sortie(f);
        return;
    }
    
    // ...
}

I'm concerned this approach might cause issues during the dynamic linking process, especially considering cross-platform compatibility.
My research suggests using structs instead of globals, but I'm unsure about the implications for Lazarus integration.
Questions:

What are the potential pitfalls of using global variables in a C library when dynamically linking with Lazarus, particularly across different platforms?
How can I refactor my code to use structs or another approach that ensures better compatibility and maintainability?
What are the best practices for writing C code that will be dynamically linked with Lazarus, considering POSIX/XSI standards for portability?
If I must retain some global variables, how should I declare and access them in Lazarus to ensure proper linking?

I've looked into resources on the Lazarus wiki about FFI, but haven't found specific guidance on handling global state in dynamically linked C libraries.
Any insights, especially from those with experience in cross-platform development involving C and Lazarus, would be greatly appreciated!

Some remarks:

Lazarus of course already comes with a working INI file library.
Assuming that a GUI application has a console (using snprintf) is already not portable, e.g. on Windows GUI applications typically don't have a console.
bundling the global variables in structs doesn't fundamentally change the global variable situation. It adds a concern for record/struct packing that must match though.
POSIX standards have little relevance in Pascal, as they require parsing C headers, which Pascal obviously can't. Moreover, FPC/Lazarus is portable, and works on Windows without POSIX emulation layers like cygwin/msys.
Global variables should work see https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/3.2.0/prog/progsu148.html#x187-1900007.1.2 .  But it is probably easier to just define a few functions to set/get to avoid a potential cross platform hazard.

FPC doesn't rely on (lib)FFI to talk to C, as Pascal is basically on the same level as C, there "just" need to be matching pascal declarations of everything you do in C.
For an more advanced list of issues see How to design a C / C++ library to be usable in many client languages?

Thank you for your detailed response and the helpful documentation about external variables in Pascal. Using getter and setter for each and every variable make my code lengthy and complex.
Question: You mentioned that console assumptions might not be portable. Could you suggest a more appropriate error handling or logging mechanism that would work well across platforms and when called from Lazarus?

Implement some logging system. As long as your writes are centralized, it is easy to redirect to whatever way is beneficial for that target  I usually have a callback (declared cdecl) that I set from Delphi/Lazarus code in C code. The Delphi code than issue to logfile for gui binaries, or to console for console binaries. The C libraries are the same.   As for complexities: that is one of the downsides of multi language development. Usually multi language programs are designed in a way to minimise the interfaces between program parts. If the interfacing is complex, reevaluate your design.
